# Throwing socket exception when connecting flutter app to the backend - Connection refused

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, http

I'm trying to connect flutter app to the backend (localhost) through the REST API endpoint but when I make the http request to the endpoint, it throws the socket exception

I'm using the following endpoint

https://10.0.2.2:5001/customers

it is working well on android emulator but not on the IOS simulator

Comment: figured it out! 10.0.2.2 is specifically used for android emulator, but for IOS, you have to get the IP address using ifconfig command in terminal